# What is the secret level in 868-HACK?

Tags: 868-hack

In the latest post on the game by the author, he mentions a "secret level". What is the secret level and how do you access it?

> Now the single-run scores are dominated by scores achieved with **the secret level**, much higher than what could be achieved with either version of .SCORE.

https://mightyvision.blogspot.pt/2017/04/868-hack-update.html

There are a few YouTube videos of folks "visiting" the secret level, but not only do they not explain how, I can't even tell which part of this is the secret level!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has finally been "spoiled" in a blog post by a game tester. There's a "cheat code".

> It is accessed by entering a CHEAT CODE of 868-565-27, where the numbers correspond to your Prog slots

https://vivafringe.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/lets-spoil-868-hacks-secret-level-and-talk-about-good-secrets-vs-bad-secrets/amp/